# Make Custom Function Available to Multiple Spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-workspace, google-apps-script-addon

I am trying to write some custom functions that can be used across all spreadsheets within my organization. My problem is I can not figure out how to make these functions on more than one spreadsheet.

I have tried creating the script from Google Sheets (via Create Script). This makes the function available on this spreadsheet but does not share it with other spreadsheets.

I have written the script from the G-Suite Developer Hub as a general script not attached to a specific spreadsheet, but I can not figure out how to share this script with all my sheets.

Is there any way to import my script or make it available to all Google Sheets files within a directory?

Comment: Try libraries. Some say that it affects performance but I have not found it to be a problem myself. Although, I've never tried it with cell functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a library and also you can try to make it work as a Add-On
[Google Libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries)